# QAbstractTableModel and QComboBox together

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt

I have a subclass of a `QAbstractTableModel` and I want to use `QComboBox` to display a dropbox for this table.

But by default it shows just the first column of my table, which is not what I want. I've tried `setModelColumn` to shows the column 1 instead of 0 but it did not work.

After having a look around in the internet, I've found 2 solutions:

1. Create another `QAbstractListModel` from the same data in the `QAbstractTableModel`
2. Use a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to hide other columns

Which is the best?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setModelColumn` should work. I would try to fix that. Perhaps you set the `modelColumn` at the wrong time, [docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcombobox.html#modelColumn-prop) have this to say about it:

> If set prior to populating the combo box, the pop-up view will not be affected and will show the first column (using this property's default value).

If this really doesn't work, and I'm quite sure it should, then use a `QSortFilterProxyModel`. This will be a lot less work and should be almost trivial.

Comment: It means I need to activate 'setModelColumn' before 'show()' of the parent widget?

Comment: I think it means setting it after the model has been loaded, but I'm not sure.